# Python/GDAL and accessing raster attribute table in ArcMap

Tags: raster, gdal, attribute-table

I am trying to build a raster attibute table using Gdal Python. My script  successfully runs until the end.

I want to read back the raster with attribute table in ArcMap. I am using ArcGIS 10.4.

After adding the raster data in ArcMap, no attribute table shows up.

Maybe I miss some part during my attribute table building process.

Could anyone please take a look at my script?

Script sample:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
from osgeo import gdalconst
import numpy as np

array=outband.ReadAsArray()
```

array example:

```
array=[[0 1 1 2 2 3 4]
       [0 1 2 2 2 3 3]
       [0 1 2 3 3 3 0]]


# creating raster attribute table
ras_at = gdal.RasterAttributeTable()
# creating a value column of unique values in raster
ras_at.CreateColumn("Value", gdalconst.GFT_Integer, gdalconst.GFU_MinMax)

# OBTAINIG VALES for column....
#vals = list(np.unique(array))
vals = np.unique(array).tolist()
vals=[i for i in vals if str(i)!='nan']
for i in range(len(vals)):
        ras_at.SetValueAsDouble(i, 0, float(vals[i]))
print ras_at.GetRowCount()

outband.SetDefaultRAT(ras_at)
```

Comment: Where do you think that your script may have gone astray?  For help here I think you need to extract a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that is not performing to your specification.  That we may be able to help with, but not a wall of code.

Comment: What needs to be imported prior to running that code snippet?  What is a test value that can be used for `array`?  The answers to both should be part of your script.

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but I think I recall that ArcGIS wouldn't read a standard GDAL RAT but if I wrote one manually to a .dbf file with the same name as the raster (a geotiff) then ArcGIS read it.